# Upgrade to Spring Boot 1.5.4 causes NoSuchBeanDefinitionException No qualifying bean of type PlatformTransactionManager

Tags: java, spring, maven, cucumber

I currently have a java web application with Spring Boot 1.3.8 and I use Maven + Cucumber + TestNG + failsafe maven plugin to run tests during build time. It works fine.

When I migrate Spring Boot to 1.5.4 I get the following error running the maven build for cucumber test. Any thoughts?

```
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type 'org.springframework.transaction.PlatformTransactionManager' available
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.getBean(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:353)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.getBean(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:340)
    at cucumber.api.spring.SpringTransactionHooks.obtainPlatformTransactionManager(SpringTransactionHooks.java:70)
    at cucumber.api.spring.SpringTransactionHooks.startTransaction(SpringTransactionHooks.java:60)
    at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor21.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at cucumber.runtime.Utils$1.call(Utils.java:37)
    at cucumber.runtime.Timeout.timeout(Timeout.java:13)
    at cucumber.runtime.Utils.invoke(Utils.java:31)
    at cucumber.runtime.java.JavaHookDefinition.execute(JavaHookDefinition.java:60)
    at cucumber.runtime.Runtime.runHookIfTagsMatch(Runtime.java:223)
    at cucumber.runtime.Runtime.runHooks(Runtime.java:211)
    at cucumber.runtime.Runtime.runBeforeHooks(Runtime.java:201)
    at cucumber.runtime.model.CucumberScenario.run(CucumberScenario.java:40)
    at cucumber.runtime.model.CucumberFeature.run(CucumberFeature.java:165)
    at cucumber.api.testng.TestNGCucumberRunner.runCucumber(TestNGCucumberRunner.java:63)
    at cucumber.api.testng.AbstractTestNGCucumberTests.feature(AbstractTestNGCucumberTests.java:21)
    at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor23.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.testng.internal.MethodInvocationHelper.invokeMethod(MethodInvocationHelper.java:108)
    at org.testng.internal.Invoker.invokeMethod(Invoker.java:661)
    at org.testng.internal.Invoker.invokeTestMethod(Invoker.java:869)
    at org.testng.internal.Invoker.invokeTestMethods(Invoker.java:1193)
    at org.testng.internal.TestMethodWorker.invokeTestMethods(TestMethodWorker.java:126)
    at org.testng.internal.TestMethodWorker.run(TestMethodWorker.java:109)
    at org.testng.TestRunner.privateRun(TestRunner.java:744)
    at org.testng.TestRunner.run(TestRunner.java:602)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunner.runTest(SuiteRunner.java:380)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunner.runSequentially(SuiteRunner.java:375)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunner.privateRun(SuiteRunner.java:340)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunner.run(SuiteRunner.java:289)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunnerWorker.runSuite(SuiteRunnerWorker.java:52)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunnerWorker.run(SuiteRunnerWorker.java:86)
    at org.testng.TestNG.runSuitesSequentially(TestNG.java:1301)
    at org.testng.TestNG.runSuitesLocally(TestNG.java:1226)
    at org.testng.TestNG.runSuites(TestNG.java:1144)
    at org.testng.TestNG.run(TestNG.java:1115)
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.testng.TestNGExecutor.run(TestNGExecutor.java:115)
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.testng.TestNGDirectoryTestSuite.executeSingleClass(TestNGDirectoryTestSuite.java:129)
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.testng.TestNGDirectoryTestSuite.execute(TestNGDirectoryTestSuite.java:113)
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.testng.TestNGProvider.invoke(TestNGProvider.java:111)
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.ForkedBooter.invokeProviderInSameClassLoader(ForkedBooter.java:203)
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.ForkedBooter.runSuitesInProcess(ForkedBooter.java:155)
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.ForkedBooter.main(ForkedBooter.java:103)
```

I have changed some Spring Boot configurations according to the release notes (1.4).
https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/wiki/Spring-Boot-1.4-Release-Notes

From:

```
@WebIntegrationTest
@ContextConfiguration(classes = WebTestConfig.class, loader = SpringApplicationContextLoader.class)
```

To:

```
@SpringBootTest(classes = WebTestConfig.class, webEnvironment = WebEnvironment.DEFINED_PORT)
```

All the rest remained the same as before.

Maven plugin:

```
<profile>
  <id>cucumber-tests</id>
  <build>
    <plugins>
      <plugin>
        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
        <artifactId>maven-failsafe-plugin</artifactId>
        <configuration>
          <includes>
            <include>**/*IT.java</include>
            <include>**/CucumberRunnerTestNG.java</include>
          </includes>
        </configuration>
      </plugin>
    </plugins>
  </build>
</profile>
```

Cucumber Test Runner:

```
@CucumberOptions(plugin = { "pretty" }, strict = true, 
     features = "src/test/features/cucumber", 
     glue = { "my.web.cucumber", "cucumber.api.spring" }, 
     monochrome = true, tags = { "~@Ignore" })
public class CucumberRunnerTestNG extends AbstractTestNGCucumberTests {
}
```

Cucumber base Steps Class:

```
package my.web.cucumber.steps;

@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
@SpringBootTest(classes = WebTestConfig.class, webEnvironment = WebEnvironment.DEFINED_PORT)
public abstract class BaseSteps<T> { ... }
```

Comment: I was able to successfully migrate from Spring Boot version 1.3.8 to 1.5.4 by following all the upgrade recommendations available on the Release Notes but first I had to migrate to version 1.4.x and then to 1.5.4. Step-by-step. There are some tricky changes in Spring Boot. Make sure you review all the items in the release notes.

Answer (score 0):

you have to use `@Transactional("transactionManagerName")`

See org.springframework.transaction.annotation.Transactional (@Transactional) annotation javadoc:-

http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/3.1.x/javadoc-api/org/springframework/transaction/annotation/EnableTransactionManagement.html

For those that wish to establish a more direct relationship between
@EnableTransactionManagement and the exact transaction manager bean to be used, the TransactionManagementConfigurer callback interface may be implemented - notice the implements clause and the @Override-annotated method below:
Your @Configuration class needs to implement TransactionManagementConfigurer interface - implement the annotationDrivenTransactionManager which will return the reference to the transactionManager that should be used.

Comment: Is this really required when using Spring Boot and @SpringBootApplication? I am not using plain Spring and XML config files. It is all wired by default by Spring Boot. It was working nice before (on production) and with the upgrade all is broken. It does not make any sense.